# List of functions $\chi_{s,a}(n)$ defined on a Group such that $\chi_{s,a}(n)\in{s,a}$ and depending on the parity

Tags: group-theory, big-list, closed-form

***Question***

Let $(G,\cdot,e)$ be a non-commutative group and $s,a \in G$ .I'm looking for interesting  functions $\chi_{s,a}:\Bbb N \rightarrow G$ witht this property

$$\chi_{s,a}(n)=
\begin{cases}
s, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
a, & \text{if $n$ is odd} 
\end{cases}$$

---

***My attempt for a closed form***

I define the power of an element of $G$ as usual. then I tried to use the function $\theta(x)=\frac 12+\frac12(-1)^x$ and define $\chi$ as follow

$$\chi_{s,a}(n)=s^{\theta(n)}a^{\theta(n+1)}$$

Since $\theta(x)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ is odd} 
\end{cases}$
 then 
$s^{\theta(n)}a^{\theta(n+1)}=
\begin{cases}
s^1a^0=se=s, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
a^0a^1=ea=a, & \text{if $n$ is odd} 
\end{cases}$

---

***Another partial attempt***

If I define a function $F_a:\{0;1\}\times G\rightarrow G$ such that for every $x\in G$

$F_a(0,x)=x$ and $F_a(1,x)=a$ then $$\chi_{s,a}(n)=F_a(\theta(n),s)$$

But here I can't find a closed form for $F_a$ involving the group operation in an interesting way that is different from $F_a(q,x)=a^qx^{|q-1|}$

---

> **I'm looking for a big list of examples of nice alternative closed forms (involving the group operation too).**

Comment: What does this have to do with group theory? The function $\chi_{a,s}$ is completely determined by the underlying set $X$ and the choice of elements $a,s \in X$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I was not sure about the Group T. Tag. I may be wrong but I thought was usefull because I'm searching for closed forms "expressed" with the group operation $\cdot$ and other things related to the group itself (as I did in my first attempt) too.